# Definition of Characteristics for the Object Property hasTopping in Different Contexts in OWL

Tags: properties, owl, protege, characteristics

Different burgers have different toppings like cheese, onions, beef, salad. Let's consider hamburgers and cheeseburgers as possible burger instances and the object property "has_Topping" to define their properties.

First, we want to model a burger factory where each burger which is produced is an instance. So, we have cheeseburger_1, hamburger_1, cheeseburger_2, hamburger_1. And each burger has its own instances of toppings, e.g.

```
<cheeseburger_1> <has_Topping> <cheese_1> ;
<has_Topping> <beef_1>.
<cheeseburger_2> <has_Topping> <cheese_2> ;
<has_Topping> <beef_2>.
```

In accorence with this, has_Topping is not functional, however inverse functional (because a topping determines on which burger it is a constitutent). Moreover, has_topping is aysmmectric and irreflexive. Right?

Second, we want to model a burger recipe database. Therefore, we have only one recipe for an original cheeseburger and hamburger. Our toppings exist only once.

```
<hamburger> <has_Topping> <beef>;
<has_Topping> <salad>.
<cheeseburger> <has_Topping> <beef>;
<has_Topping> <cheese>.
```

In accorence with this, has_Topping is not functional and not inverse functional (because a topping does not determine on which burger it is a constitutent). Moreover, has_topping is aysmmectric and irreflexive. Right?

Are the selected characteristics correct according to the particular use cases or is there a thinking error?

Comment: Looks reasonable... Perhaps you could rename `has_topping` to `has_piece_of_topping` (or something like) in the first case. BTW, have you seen [`pizza.owl`](https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin thanks for your quick reply. Yes, I have seen pizza.owl and I think they do not explicitly state to which case their ontology belongs. So, if you have an the other case in your mind, it is hard to understand their modeling choices. That is why I would like to hear a second opinion on this issue. Thank you very much.